# 405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed for IIS7

Tags: iis-7

I have deployed an asp.net application on webserver having IIS7. After I start to browse the URL https://testing123.test.com/mywebsite/

In the default document section of the IIS7 I have set Default.aspx as the default landing page.

I tried the following URL :

https://testing123.test.com/mywebsite/Default.aspx

On both the above cases, I am getting the following error :

```
405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.
```

Can any one help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: The site: https://testing123.test.com/mywebsite is using ADFS authentication. There was a problem in the url that was registered in the ADFS. Hence when I was trying to browse the url it was throwing error :405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed. The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.Now the url is properly registered for ADFS and it is working properly.